# Limit the output variables of CP-SAT solver

Tags: variables, model, or-tools, cp-sat

The following data is given as df:

| id | class | country | weigths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | US | 20 |
| b | 2 | US | 5 |
| a | 2 | CH | 5 |
| a | 1 | CH | 10 |
| b | 1 | CH | 5 |
| c | 1 | US | 10 |
| b | 2 | GER | 15 |
| a | 2 | CH | 5 |
| c | 1 | US | 15 |
| a | 1 | US | 10 |

The goal is to create an alternative allocation of the columns weight but keep the distribution of unique values in id, class and country. For example: 5 of 10 values -> 50% in column id are "a". An alternative solution for weights should keep this distribution of a = 50%. And all other distribution of each unique value in the first three columns.

For this I created the following code to get a dict with the distribution:

```py
constraint_columns = ["id", "class", "country"]
constraints = {}

for column in constraint_columns:
    constraints[column] = dict(zip(df.groupby([column]).sum().reset_index()[column], 
df.groupby([column]).sum().reset_index()["weights"]))
```

The result looks as follows:

```py
{'id': {'a': 50, 'b': 25, 'c': 25},
'class': {1: 70, 2: 30},
'country': {'CH': 25, 'GER': 15, 'US': 60}}
```

I then initiate the model, create the variables for the model to solve (weights) and create the constraints by looping through my constraints and map them with the variables:

```py
model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

count = 0
dict_weights = {}

for weight in range(len(df)):
    dict_weights[count] = model.NewIntVar(0, 100, f"weight_{count}")
    count += 1

weights_full = []

for weight in dict_weights:
    weights_full.append(dict_weights[weight])
```

I give a 5% range where the distribution can be different:

```py
for constraint in constraints:
    for key in constraints[constraint]:
        keys = df.loc[df[constraint] == key].index
        model.Add(sum(list(map(dict_weights.get, keys))) >= int(constraints[constraint][key] * 1 - ((constraints[constraint][key] * 1) * 0.05)))
        model.Add(sum(list(map(dict_weights.get, keys))) <= int(constraints[constraint][key] * 1 + ((constraints[constraint][key] * 1) * 0.05)))
```

I solve the model and everything works fine:

```py
solver.parameters.cp_model_presolve = False  # type: ignore
solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 0.01  # type: ignore
solution_collector = VarArraySolutionCollector(weights_full)

solver.SolveWithSolutionCallback(model, solution_collector)
solution_collector.solution_list
```

Solution:

```py
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 15, 15, 23, 35]
```

In a next step I want to tell the model, that the result should consist out of a specific number of weights. For example: 3 - That would mean that 5 weight values should be 0 and only 3 are used to find a solution that fits the distribution. Right now it does not matter if there is a feasible solution or not.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. the solver is integral. 0.05 will be silently rounded to 0 by python.
2. I do not understand your problem. My gut reaction is to create one bool var per weight value and per item, and convert all constraints to weighted sums of these bool variables.